# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle' when dequeuing tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uinib

I have no clue why I am getting this error and I have tried looking at other answers, but could not find a solution.

The code in question:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    messagesTableView?.register(UINib.init(nibName: "messageTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "messageTableViewCell")

    messagesTableView.delegate = self;
    messagesTableView.dataSource = self;
    dataSrc.delegate = self


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MessagesTableViewCell {

        cell.configureWithItem(item: dataArray[indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

When tableView.dequeueReusableCell is called I get the error. I have also made sure the identifier for the cell is set to "messageTableViewCell"

Comment: Please make sure you have a nib name with `MessageTableViewCell `

Comment: I am an idiot, I didn't have the nib file. thanks

Comment: No problem, it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're initializing `UINib`, as `nibName` parameter you have to pass name of the file

[image]

```
UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
```

so in your case I suppose your file is named same as your class `MessagesTableViewCell`

```
messagesTableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "MessagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "messageTableViewCell")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have created a `nib/xib` file named as `MessageTableViewCell`, then register the nib file `MessageTableViewCell`,

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MessageTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "messageTableViewCell")
```